# How to export endpoint ip from service description in kubernetes - Go template

Tags: mysql, go, export, go-templates

i have a service runinig inside kubernetes, and i need to extract the exndpoint ip in environment variable

Here's the informations about the service

```
 kubectl get endpoints
NAME                ENDPOINTS                                                     AGE
kubernetes          10.0.2.15:8443                                                5h
locations-service   172.17.0.4:8080,172.17.0.5:8080,172.17.0.4:8081 + 1 more...   2h
mysql               172.17.0.7:3306                                               3h
phpmyadmin          172.17.0.6:80                                                 5h
```

How i can get the Endpoints value and export it to a variable?
i tried the following but it's not working

```
export PORT=$(kubectl describe service  mysql -o go-template='{{range.spec.endpoints}}')
```

Answer (score 0):

this will get the ip value of mysql service

```
 export PORT=$(kubectl get endpoints -o go-template='{{range.items}}{{if eq .metadata.name "mysql"}}{{(index (index .subsets 0).addresses 0).ip}}{{end}}{{end}}')
```